# convert a json column to utf8mb4

Tags: php, mysql, json, alter, utf8mb4

in a mysql insert request i used (`$text` being sent by `$_POST` and column `MESSAGE` being of JSON format) :

```
$data = '{"mytext":".'$text'."}';

INSERT INTO xxxxx (MESSAGE) VALUES('$mytext');
```

i was stuck with the following problem :

> Some smiley are displaying ok, but some with a "?"

I searched here for an answer and found that utf8mb4 must be set on the database, tables and columns.

**The problem** is when i try the following which contains my registered message:

```
ALTER TABLE xxxxx CHANGE column_name column_name JSON CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Result of the above**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;

I assume that it is only possible on `Varchar()` column.

Do you have any idea on how i can make this work ?

Thank you

Comment: You're open to SQL injection!! This is a huge security risk! Don't use your code in a real life application!!

Comment: What is the full error message, it must point to some specific part that it deems incorrect ("near ...").

Comment: this is not th actual production code, i have a secure_input() function which real escape and strip.

Comment: The exact error message is : ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 1 > that's why i assume that converting a json column to utf8mb4 is not relevant

Comment: It has nothing to do with the contents of the table, it means that `... column_name JSON CHARACTER SET ...` is an invalid query.

Comment: @deceze  When i do  column_name varchar(xx)   it doesn't throw any error, so i assume that is the problem.

Comment: What was the table definition _before_ converting to JSON?

Answer (score 2):

> Some smiley are displaying ok, but some with a "?"

Start by finding the problems that cause "question mark" from [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

In particular:

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8mb4. Fix this.
- The column in the database is not CHARACTER SET utf8mb4. Fix this. (Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see what it is currently.)
- Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8.

To discuss further, please provide

- the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` before attempting the `ALTER`.  (I suspect the `VARCHAR` is currently `CHARACTER SET utf8`.)
- the full error message.  (I guess it says "near 'CHARACTER...'".)
- what version of MySQL you are using.

The manual say "MySQL handles strings used in JSON context using the utf8mb4 character set and utf8mb4_bin collation.", I deduce that you do not need to specify either charset or collation for datatype `JSON`.

Comment: this point makes sense `The manual say "MySQL handles strings used in JSON context using the utf8mb4 character set and utf8mb4_bin collation.", I deduce that you do not need to specify either charset or collation for datatype JSON`

Comment: @danish_wani - That is a simple question on the surface, but it is complex under the covers.  I don't know the answer offhand; I'll do some research.

Comment: @danish_wani - I am pretty sure that, at least in MySQL 8.0, you are forced into utf8mb4 and don't need to do anything.  (I tried a table with a _different_ default charset; it was happy.  However that may not be the only test needed.)

Comment: Yes, my problem was storing currency symbols into the MySQL DB with default charset as latin1, but it threw error on most of the symbols then I thought I may have to change the charset but when I inserted the same currency symbols data into the json field without changing the character set it worked fine and stored the symbols as they were.

Comment: @danish_wani - It seems that a column with datatype `JSON` is encoded using utf8mb4 (no choice), while `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` allow setting a charset (such as latin1).

Comment: Yes, that's true. Thank you. Appreciated

Comment: @danish_wani - Thank you.  I learned something.